# Can lambdas be STL-adaptable?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, functor, std

"Make functor classes adaptable" - told Scott Meyers in Effective STL, item 40. There is a question - can lambda-functions be adaptable? (Lambdas doesn't provide access to the inheritance mechanism, right?)

Comment: Does he really suggest polymorphism? That's really curious. Anyway, you would capture a lambda in a `std::function` if you cannot pass it directly to the consumer-template. Just like any other kind of callable.

Comment: This entire item is obsoleted by c++11 and should be ignored. You just don't use `not1` or `bind2nd` these days. These things are deprecated and/or removed from the standard. Lambdas and `std::bind` replace them, and you don't need to adapt anything for `std::bind`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That item is not talking about inheritance, but about composition.

Prior to C++11, if you wanted to invert the output of a unary predicate, you would define `argument_type` and `result_type` member types, so you could wrap it in `std::not1`.

Or if you wanted to partially apply a binary operation, you would define `first_argument_type`, `second_argument_type` and `result_type`, to pass it to `std::bind1st` or `std::bind2nd`.

You don't get to add members to a lambda's type, so you can't use them with the old adaptors.